# MS Visual Studio 2013 common tools folder

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, path, cmd, environment-variables

Trying to compile a C program through cmd but I got the error message "cl is not recognized..etc) hence added the the C:\Windows\System32 to the environment variable as well as the bin folder from the Visual Studio 12.0 directory

Ive also tried following these instructions https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx , then I get an error message "cannot determine VS common tools folder"

Getting very frustrated as Ive tried pretty much all I could think of

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE` and `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\amd64` in my PATH for VS 2008. Just FYI.

Comment: Do you know you can run builds from a Visual Studio command prompt with the environment pre-configured, or are you deliberately setting up the environment manually? If you want the preconfigured, go to Programs->Visual Studio 2013->Visual Studio Tools and click on one of the command prompt links.

Comment: I decided to just give up on MS VS. Too complicated for my liking, as all I needed was a simple C compiler. Thank you for your help though!